# Write-Error not displaying error in console when triggered through Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell

I am encountering an issue with my PowerShell script where the 'Write-Error' function is not displaying the error in the console when triggered through 'Register-ObjectEvent'.

Here is my script:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
  Start-Sleep 3
  Write-Error 'sample Error'
}

$ps = [powershell]::Create()
$null = $ps.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
$handle = $ps.BeginInvoke()
$e = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps -EventName 'InvocationStateChanged' -Action {
  Write-Warning 'event fired'
  if($event.Sender.HadErrors)
  {
    foreach($ErrorItem in $event.Sender.Streams.Error)
    {
      Write-Warning ('[Error Exception] {0}' -f $ErrorItem.Exception)
      Write-Error -Exception $ErrorItem.Exception
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this script, I get the following output in the console:

```
WARNING: event fired 
WARNING: [Error Exception] Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: sample Error
```

As you can see, the 'Write-Error' function is being executed, but the error is not being displayed in the console.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the design rationale, but how **output streams from `-Action` script blocks** are handled is surprising (written as of PowerShell 7.3.3):

- Only the *success* and *error* [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) are captured in the event job returned from the [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) call.

  - That is, you must collect such output *on demand*, later, using [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job)
- All *other* output streams, as well as to-host output ([`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) and [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)) print *directly* to the host (console).

  - That is, such output prints *right away*, and *cannot be captured*.
  - Note that the fact that it prints right away means that it can interfere with display output being produced in the foreground thread.

Things to note about error output from an `-Action` script block:

- It is seemingly *not* recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), the session-wide log of errors.
- If a *terminating* error occurs - whether *statement*- (e.g., `[int]::Parse('foo')`) or *script*-terminating (e.g. `throw 'Aborting'`) - execution of the script block is *quietly* aborted.
- However, all error types *are* recorded in the event job, so you can inspect them via `Receive-Job` later.

---

As for **what you tried** and **workarounds**:

Given the above, your [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning) call's output printed right way, while the [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error)'s output did not.

A simple way to make your error output *also* print right away is to redirect to the success output stream with `2>&1` and pipe to `Out-Host`:

```
Write-Error -Exception $ErrorItem.Exception 2>&1 | Out-Host
```

This still allows you to inspect the error via `Receive-Job` later.

By contrast, if you wanted to send *success*-output stream to *both* the event job and directly to the host, you'd need *two* output operations: once via `Out-Host`, and separately to the success output stream; e.g.:

```
# First, output to the host with Out-Host, but also capture
# the output in a variable.
($out = 'to the success output stream') | Out-Host
# Second, output the captured output to the success output stream,
# so it can also be retrieved via Receive-Job later.
$out
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might be a way around this limitation with `PSEventJob` in PowerShell. There are 2 requirements for this, the first one is to initialize the event from within an advanced function or script block and to pass [`$PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) to the event's [SessionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmoduleinfo.sessionstate?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-psmoduleinfo-sessionstate). The second requirement is to wait for the task to be completed, which also means, blocking the thread.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```bash
function Test-Event {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([scriptblock] $ScriptBlock)

    & $ScriptBlock
}

Test-Event {
    $stdin  = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[object]]::new()
    $stdout = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[object]]::new()

    $ScriptBlock = {
        Start-Sleep 1
        Write-Error 'Sample Error'
        Start-Sleep 1
        'foo'
        Start-Sleep 1
        'bar'
        Start-Sleep 1
        'baz'
        Start-Sleep 1
        Write-Error 'Sample Error 2'
        Start-Sleep 1
    }

    $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $handle = $ps.BeginInvoke($stdin, $stdout)

    $params = @{
        InputObject      = $stdout
        EventName        = 'DataAdding'
        SourceIdentifier = 'PSInstance.DataAddingStdOut'
        Action           = { $cmdlet.WriteObject($EventArgs.ItemAdded) }
    }
    $sub = Register-ObjectEvent @params
    $sub.Module.SessionState.PSVariable.Set('cmdlet', $PSCmdlet)

    $params = @{
        InputObject      = $ps.Streams.Error
        EventName        = 'DataAdding'
        SourceIdentifier = 'PSInstance.DataAddingStdErr'
        Action           = { $cmdlet.WriteError($EventArgs.ItemAdded) }
    }
    $sub = Register-ObjectEvent @params
    $sub.Module.SessionState.PSVariable.Set('cmdlet', $PSCmdlet)

    try {
        while(-not $handle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) { }
    }
    finally {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier PSInstance.DataAddingStdOut
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier PSInstance.DataAddingStdErr
        $ps.Dispose()
    }
}
```